# Select names starting with the range from A to L

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-workbench

im working on this table 'Empleados'

```
idEmpleado
nombreEmmpleado
hijosEmpleado
```

Im trying this select on mysql workbench, but not working

```
select nombreEmpleado from empleados where nombreEmpleado like '[A-L]%' order by nombreEmpleado
```

I need to show all names starting with the range from A to L. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use REGEXP like that:

```
  WHERE nombreEmpleado REGEXP '^[A-L]'
```